# What is the correct format of the query for Search Requests to Spotify's Web API

Tags: rest, http, spotify

I want to send search requests to Spotify's Web API. They have a [search endpoint described in their docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/search). The URL query requires two parameters:

1. `type` of the searched item (i.e. album or track)
2. `q` which is the actual search query

The format of `q` is not clear to me. I can just enter search terms. For example if I want to find the song 'As It Was' from 'Harry Styles' I can just enter `As It Was Harry Styles` and the first returned item is the correct song. So far so good. But the description for `q` states that:

> You can narrow down your search using field filters. The available filters are album, artist, track, year, upc, tag:hipster, tag:new, isrc, and genre. Each field filter only applies to certain result types.

They even provide an example:

```
remaster%20track:Doxy%20artist:Miles%20Davis
```

Using filters seems much more secure and better to me than just enter any terms into `q`. Especially, because for the items I search for, I will always have the title and the artist. But the problem is, I always receive empty responses. Even with the provided example query (and yes, that song exists, I looked it up (you can use literally the example query in the search interface of your Spotify app)).

So how do I use these filters?

What is this `remaster` in the begin? Just another search term?

Has anybody some experience with this and can help?

Unfortunately, I could not find anything on the web describing the query in more detail.

Comment: You can play around with [the console](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/) for the Search for Item endpoint.  Also, which programming language are you using/planning to use?

Comment: I think I figured it out. But I would have expected that the documentation for an API of such a big web company documents things like this.

I plan to use Dart. There will be just some little scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this more for myself, as it seems you've figured this out. The current documentation on the website sucks, there is some more [extensive search documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120704131650/http://www.spotify.com/us/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/) and [some examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20120530041326/http://www.spotify.com/us/blog/archives/2008/01/22/searching-spotify/) from 2008 on the wayback machine. I grabbed these from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437820/how-can-i-search-for-albums-with-generic-titles-using-the-spotify-web-api?rq=4). So based on this and my own experimentation I've found:

1. Don't use [HTML URL encoding characters](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) in your request, why they are in the example is beyond me.
2. Use colons after the filter, and then enclose the search term in quotation marks. For your example the syntax would be `track:"As It Was" artist:"Harry Styles"`. If your search terms don't have spaces in them you can forget the quotation marks, such as `track:Yellow artist:Coldplay`, but it won't hurt to use them

As for what `remaster` is doing at the start of the example query, I have no idea